# Remove gap between lines of flex blocks

Tags: html, css

how can I remove the gap between the lines of flex blocks?

I have a certain number of red blocks, which may vary. When the number of blocks is small, the distance between the lines is large; when there is a large number, there is none. How to remove a gap with a small quantity.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 3px black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container-red-box {
  width: 25%;
}

.red-box {
  margin: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: solid 3px black;
}

.container-boxs {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-boxs">
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

10 blocks:

[image]

40 blocks:
[image]

Comment: align-content: start on .container-boxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding `align-items: flex-start` to the `.container`. By default in the flex layout, [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) is behaving as `stretch`, which will make its children try to occupy the entire cross-axis. By setting it to `flex-start` (or `start`), it will make them occupy only the necessary space.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 3px black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  /* added */
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container-red-box {
  width: 25%;
}

.red-box {
  margin: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: solid 3px black;
}

.container-boxs {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-boxs">
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is doing that because it is trying to evenly fill the container with the row wraps. If you change the `height: 500px;` on `.container` to `max-height: 500px;`, it will get rid of the gaps

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 3px black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container-red-box {
  width: 25%;
}

.red-box {
  margin: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: solid 3px black;
}

.container-boxs {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-boxs">
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-red-box">
        <div class="red-box"></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my task means that the window with blocks must be clearly 500px height, no more, no less. And if there are 10 blocks, then the window will be smaller.